# Why are some OCRed pdfs greppable, and some aren't?

Tags: pdf, grep

So let's say I have 10 files that are searchable using pdfgrep

Of those, some are searchable using grep and some aren't

Why's that? what's the trait that allows a pdf to be greppbale?

Answer (score 1):

A without specifying what the source of these PDFs is, it's hard to say for certain but a PDF can be one of a few things:

- An actual text document, strings, formatting instructions, etc. Easily greppable.
- An image that has been run through an OCR mechanism to embed text under the image. Easily greppable.
- An image of a piece of paper. Not greppable.

I would suggest the ones you can't use haven't had their OCR done. There are processes for doing it but that's a slightly bigger question.

Comment: Thanks  
I'm certain that all my PDFs are OCRed, as I executed a script on my PDFs that deletes every PDF that pdfgrep can't match the search string "ISBN" to..